# Media player is not play after onActivityResult

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create a fullscreen button

first a fragment play the video , and when I click on the button, it play the video in activity, and the progress need to maintain.

Here is the code of **fragment**

```
 full_screen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), VideoFullScreen.class);
                i.putExtra("video_url", video_url);
                i.putExtra("time", player.getCurrentPosition());
                startActivityForResult(i, intent_code); //random intent number
            }
        });

 @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        player.stopPlayback();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == intent_code) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                player.seekTo((int)data.getIntExtra("time", 0));
                player.start();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for activity

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("time", (int)player.getCurrentPosition());
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

    player.stopPlayback();
    player.release();

    super.onStop();
}
```

The problem is the video is not play after activity finish, it is due to the player release , but it need to be there to release resource if I go to the page other than FullScreen,

also the `player.start()` is not trigger even if I remove the line `player.release();`

How to fix it? Thanks for helping

Comment: Did you check if your onActivityResult is being called when returned from the full screen activity?
Try placing the player.start() in the onResume function inside the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't put your whole fragment's code in your question so I'm guessing. You should put your player setup code in onResume. In onActivityResult, save the time to a member variable and onResume do the seek. First launch it should seek to 0 and subsequent activity results will seek to whatever is set in the result intent.